# How come if I play a video when online on a website and then turn off the wifi, the video still plays for the part that loaded?

Tags: google-chrome, video

How come if I play a video when online on a website and then turn off the wifi, the video still plays for the part that loaded? Where does loaded part of the video get stored when offline?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the video's still playing is called data buffer.
[WikiPedia explains this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

#### In your special case of video streaming:

To create the illusion of a continuous stream of video, the player creates a buffer(cache) that contains several time slices ahead of the current time frame to avoid that each slight connection interruption would lead to a dropout in the display of the video.

In browsers, the buffer is located in the *browser cache* [and is explained in this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/firefox-cache/). This article explains where the cache of Firefox is located. Unfortunately this differs from version to version and from browser to browser. An exception is the *Adobe Flash Player* cache which is not located in the normal *browser cache*, but in a separate *Flash* directory (Look for the Adobe Flash Data Directory).

So to locate it browser-independently, you'd have to check a lot of possible places.